# Why do we have signed integers for timestamps in core with 2038 timestamp date bug in mind?

Tags: 7, datetime

So I couldn't find a Drupal specific documentation about this, and I know this is far off into the future, but it seems to me the way we currently use timestamps in Drupal will invoke the [2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) right about when our kids graduate college.

I hope I am missing the obvious here, but looking at node table for example all created and updated timestamps are not 'unsigned' integers. According to this [SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25361/why-does-unix-store-timestamps-in-a-signed-integer) and this [mysql issue](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1872) having timestamps as unsigned integers kicks the ball down the road for several generations till 2116 (when I assume there won't be a need for CMS because we will all know everything) so... shouldn't we be using unsigned integers?

Comment: That should better be discussed on drupal.org

Comment: (facepalm) that's a good point... not sure how I missed it but it is already in issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/65474  the issue is 4 years old will bump it